# Not enough physical memory is available to power on this virtual machine with its configured settings - VMWare Workstation 17.0.2

Tags: kernel, 22.04, ram, vmware, vmware-workstation

After recently bumping up my RAM to 64GB to freely toy with some more powerful VMs, I've disappointingly found I'm unable to boot anything with more than 3668 MB of RAM allocated - VMWare itself is able to see all 64GB of physical memory and an 8GB swap file.

I'll list a few points which I hope may be of use:

-Host OS: Ubuntu 22.04

-Hypervisor: VMWare Workstation 17.0.2

-Kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic

-free -m shows 56.8GB in free memory

-VT-X is confirmed to be working without issue

-Secure Boot is disabled

I've attempted to fix this using a patch found at: https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/, the output is as follows:

```
user@system:~/Downloads/vmkrnl/sol2$ wget https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/workstation-17.0.2.tar.gz
--2023-08-26 09:39:19--  https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/workstation-17.0.2.tar.gz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 20.248.137.48
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|20.248.137.48|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://codeload.github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/tar.gz/refs/heads/workstation-17.0.2 [following]
--2023-08-26 09:39:19--  https://codeload.github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/tar.gz/refs/heads/workstation-17.0.2
Resolving codeload.github.com (codeload.github.com)... 20.248.137.55
Connecting to codeload.github.com (codeload.github.com)|20.248.137.55|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘workstation-17.0.2.tar.gz’

workstation-17.0.2.tar.gz                                [ <=>                                                                                                                  ] 470.78K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s    

2023-08-26 09:39:20 (4.55 MB/s) - ‘workstation-17.0.2.tar.gz’ saved [482077]

user@system:~/Downloads/vmkrnl/sol2$ tar -xzf workstation-17.0.2.tar.gz
user@system:~/Downloads/vmkrnl/sol2$ cd vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.0.2
user@system:~/Downloads/vmkrnl/sol2/vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.0.2$ tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
user@system:~/Downloads/vmkrnl/sol2/vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.0.2$ tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
user@system:~/Downloads/vmkrnl/sol2/vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.0.2$ sudo cp -v vmmon.tar vmnet.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/
'vmmon.tar' -> '/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar'
'vmnet.tar' -> '/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar'
user@system:~/Downloads/vmkrnl/sol2/vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.0.2$ sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
[AppLoader] Use shipped Linux kernel AIO access library.
An up-to-date "libaio" or "libaio1" package from your system is preferred.
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/moduleloop.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/sharedAreaVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/statVarsVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/bootstrap/bootstrap.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/bootstrap/vmmblob.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  MODPOST /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
  BTF [M] /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  MODPOST /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
  BTF [M] /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-9siDeM/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual ethernet                                                    done
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Shared Memory Available                                             done
```

I'm a bit lost on where to go from here, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for VMware support ?